# Package inputenc Error: Unicode character ∙ (U+2219)

Tags: math-mode, amsmath, packages

I'm using this packages:

```
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[greek,italian]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1,T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{sidecap}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
```

I was trying to make this math formula:

```
$-8.37 \pm (0.163∙3) = -8.37 \pm 0.489($°$\frac{cm^2}{g}$
```

but this error pops out:

```
Package inputenc Error: Unicode character ∙ (U+2219)
(inputenc) not set up for use with LaTeX.
See the inputenc package documentation for explanation.
Type H <return> for immediate help.
...
l.297 $6.59 \pm (0.198∙
3) = 6.59 \pm 0.594($°$\frac{cm^2}{g}$
You may provide a definition with
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter
```

How can I solve it?

This is what I need as final result: https://1drv.ms/u/s!AnVvgK9aqru2mCSUw50zblzinU7L?e=HpdqRS

Comment: You should not write units that way, see the `siunitx` package. And what is `$°$` suppose to do here?

Comment: $°$ is because i need it to write it like that, but I already have the siunitx package, i just want to know how do i fix this error

Comment: You are not using `siunitx` to format the unit an you should. I ask again what does `$°$` mean here? Is it a unit? I have never seen a syntax like this

Comment: I solve it the problem was this central dot "  ∙  " I solve it by taping \cdot command

Comment: ° this is used for saying "degrees" like "°C" or 180°.

Comment: That is also available in `siunitx`, still looks very strange

Comment: Are you looking for `$-8.37 \pm (0.163\cdot3) = -8.37 \pm 0,489$~(\unit[per-mode=fraction]{\degree\cm\squared\per\gram})`? (using `siunitx`)

Answer (score 1):

The error is clear enough: The unicode character ∙ (U+2219) is not set up for use with LaTeX.  There are ways to use the character, but it's better to use `\cdot` for that symbol, as intended.

But as several people commented, you're loading `siunitx` but not using any of its capabilities.  It would be better to typeset it as

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
$-8.37 \pm (0.163\cdot3)
= \SI[per-mode=fraction, separate-uncertainty=true]{-8.37 \pm 0.489}{\degree\cm\squared\per\gram}$
\end{document}
```

[image: code output]

This has the advantage that you could collect all of the siunitx options at the beginning of your document, so that if you changed your mind about how to display this, you could change a few lines at the beginning instead of looking through your entire document.

Answer (score 0):

To expand on Teepeemm’s answer, one way to set up the Unicode character to work in math mode is

```
\usepackage{newunicodechar}
\newunicodechar{^^^^2219}{\cdot}
```

Alternatively, you can switch to `unicode-math`, which sets the symbol up in both text and math mode.  If you want to use the symbol in text mode in legacy LaTeX, it’s possible (but not recommended) to use `\ensuremath{\cdot}` instead of `\cdot`.